# Regular expression help needed for parsing strings in any order

Tags: java, regex

I need to parse the following string with a regular expression. I would like to parse this string with any spaces between the parameters, and parameters in a different order. The string allways starts with ECC but other paramters like ID can come in the last and signature can come in the beginning after ECC.

```
EAN CID=55505, APIKey=cbrzfta369qwyrm9t5b8y8kf, Signature=60955d3260415e69c0a305c42083415b
```

Currently I am using the below regular expression

```
^EAN cid=([0-9]+), *apikey=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(, *signature=([a-fA-F0-9]+))?$
```

but it is not working if the parameters are in the reverse order.

For ex:

```
ECC Signature=60955d3260415e69c0a305c42083415b, Key=cbrzfta369qwyrm9t5b8y8kf, Id=123
```

Please help me out by correcting my regular expression if possible.

Comment: You say that every string starts with `ECC`, but half of your examples start with `EAN`. What's going on here?

Comment: In such cases it is usually easier to use other methods for parsing like `String.split` or `Scanner`. Or you use regular expressions for just getting the keys-value pairs.

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/cT9aV2/1

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea using `String.split()`, that puts the result in a `HashMap` so you can easily pull out the parameters by key name.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      String params = "ECC Signature=60955d3260415e69c0a305c42083415b, Key=cbrzfta369qwyrm9t5b8y8kf, Id=123";
      String[] parsed = params.split("=|,\\s*" );
      System.out.println( Arrays.toString( parsed ) );
      Map<String,String> paramMap = arrayToMap( parsed );
      System.out.println( paramMap );
   }

   private static Map<String, String> arrayToMap(String[] parsed) {
      Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
      for( int i = 0; i+1 < parsed.length; i+=2 ) 
         map.put( parsed[i],parsed[i+1]);
      return map;
   }
```

I left the `arrayToMap` method parameterized so it was easy to follow, but it could be made generic as follows (EDIT: more clever generic code):

```
   public static <T,U extends T> Map<T, T> arrayToMap( U[] parsed) {
      Map<T,T> map = new HashMap<>();
      for( int i = 0; i+1 < parsed.length; i+=2 ) 
         map.put( parsed[i],parsed[i+1]);
      return map;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

One sample for your ECC's requirement. FYI.

```
    String base = "(?:\\s*(?:(?:id=([0-9]+))|(?:key=([a-zA-Z0-9]+))|(?:signature=([a-fA-F0-9]+))),?)";
    String patternStr ="ECC " + base + "+$"; 
    String str = "ECC Signature=60955d3260415e69c0a305c42083415b, Key=cbrzfta369qwyrm9t5b8y8kf, Id=123";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternStr, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(str);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(0));
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
        System.out.println(m.group(2));
        System.out.println(m.group(3));
    }
```

The output is :

```
ECC Signature=60955d3260415e69c0a305c42083415b, Key=cbrzfta369qwyrm9t5b8y8kf, Id=123
123
cbrzfta369qwyrm9t5b8y8kf
60955d3260415e69c0a305c42083415b
```

if the input string is:

```
String str = "ECC Id=123,  Key=cbrzfta369qwyrm9t5b8y8kf,  Signature=60955d3260415e69c0a305c42083415b";
```

The output is :

```
ECC Id=123,  Key=cbrzfta369qwyrm9t5b8y8kf,  Signature=60955d3260415e69c0a305c42083415b
123
cbrzfta369qwyrm9t5b8y8kf
60955d3260415e69c0a305c42083415b
```

Comment: Thank you very much for looking into this.                                  (?:\\s*(?:(?:id=([0-9]+))|(?:key=([a-zA-Z0-9]+))|(?:signature=([a-fA-F0-9]+))),?)                                                  This is not working for me. The java pattern matcher is not able to divide into any groups